# plotting multiple dataframes as one plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot

I searched through this forum and unfortunatelly I do not know what am I doing wrong.
I have three .csv files
file1.csv

```
name     value     type
model1   100.1     all
model2   121.1     all
model3   151.1     all
```

file2.csv

```
name     value     type
model1   110.1     one
model2   131.1     one
model3   141.1     one
model4   161.1     one
model5   171.1     one
```

file3.csv

```
name     value     type
model1   80.1      two
model2   85.1      two
model3   90.1      two
model4   92.1      two
model5   94.1      two
```

and i want to make plot which shows all three 'value' bars for each 'name' - thats why I add "type" column.

So I made dataframe from each .csv file and named them df_file1, df_file2, df_file3. So I tried to make a plot:

```
df_all = pd.concat([df_file1, df_file2, df_file3])
ax = (
     df_all
).plot(kind="bar", rot=45, figsize=(20,6), grid = True, color=['r', 'g', 'y'])

for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container)
```

but unfortunatelly my plot shows three bars for df_file1, five bars for df_file2, five bars for df_file3 instead of three bars for model1, three bars for model2,three bars for model3,three bars for model4 and three bars for model5 with each bar in different column

Is there any way to make a plot just as I disribed it?

Comment: `df_all.pivot('name', 'type', 'value').plot(kind='bar')
` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try [pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) your data first, so that each column represents a `type` and each row represents your `name`:

```
df_piv = df_all.pivot('name', 'type', 'value')
```

[out]

```
type      all    one   two
name                      
model1  100.1  110.1  80.1
model2  121.1  131.1  85.1
model3  151.1  141.1  90.1
model4    NaN  161.1  92.1
model5    NaN  171.1  94.1
```

Then the plotting command you were using:

```
df_piv.plot(kind='bar', rot=45, figsize=(20,6), grid=True, color=['r', 'g', 'y'])
```

[out]

[image]